# No permissions found in manifest for: []7 :Flutter android

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I have added in manifest this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

but still getting this error in console
No permissions found in manifest for: []7

I am using permission handler,for permission managing

I tried adding this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
     android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

You can also change the `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`.